# Cyrillic displays as ??? ???? in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, cyrillic

I'm trying to print values from the database, containing countrylist. One of the fields in this database is cyrilic. My PHP script looks like this:

```
include_once("db.php");

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM country");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

do {
    $id = strtolower($row["id"]);
    $value = ($row["runame"]);
    echo $id . " " . $value . '<br/>';
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query));
```

The output from this script looks like this:

```
ad ???????
ae ???????????? ???????? ???????
af ??????????
ag ??????? ? ???????
ai ????????
```

So, apparently I need to set UTF-8 for this PHP script... somehow... Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Btw, `strtolower` is for single byte characters only.

Comment: Why not change do...while() to while(){} end get rid of the 1-st fetch_array() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to MySQL:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Or if you are using cp1251 in the database, set this encoding.

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Comment: "Using mysql_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended." http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php